# Custom gestures from raw touch events on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, multi-touch, uitouch, custom-keyboard

How do I receive raw touch events on iOS for creating my own gestures using my own state machine? I'm looking for the analogue of Android's [`MotionEvent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) for multi-touch gestures. I need to be able to draw on the background box, but I do not need OS components on this box.

iOS provides a gesture recognizer for defining custom gestures, and it defines [`UITouch`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitouch) objects that deliver to the application. However, the former is incapable of the implementing the complexity of my system, particularly at the efficiency I need, and the latter does preprocessing, such as to determine the [`tapCount`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitouch/1618132-tapcount). My system must itself decide whether a touch is a tap or not.

Additionally, I need to ascertain for myself whether multiple simultaneously-touching fingers form a gesture or not. I can't have iOS interpreting four-finger gestures input (exclusively) on top of my viewing area, though I could live with iOS interpreting five-finger gestures. It's okay for iOS to preempt control from my view if any finger of the gesture starts outside of the view.

The application is a gesturing alternative to the keyboard, so it would ideally be able to operate in the keyboard area, in case this affects the answer.

Is this possible on iOS? What's the approach? I'd like to write a simple program outputting touch events to prove it can be done. Thanks for your help!

UPDATE: I was largely able to answer the question by playing with the Multitouch Visualizer app. Each tap is registered as it occurs, and gestures of 4 fingers or fewer appear to be received without iOS interfering. iOS takes over for some 5 finger gestures, but only if they satisfy certain (unknown) initial characteristics. I don't know how this is done, but I imagine via `UITouch` events.

Comment: Usually, if you want to do something more low level than gesture recognizers, you use [`touchesBegan`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621142-touchesbegan), [`touchesMoved`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621107-touchesmoved), [`touchedEnded`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621084-touchesended), etc. And with this you can use coalesced touches (e.g. more than 60 touches per second), predictive touches, etc. Perhaps you can describe why this is incapable of implementing the desired complexity.

Comment: By the way, have you seen the relevant WWDC videos, e.g. [Leveraging Touch Input on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/220/) (ignore the bit on Apple Pencil if you want) and [Advanced Touch Input on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/233/)?

Comment: Read the documentation for `UIGestureRecognizer` and the section on subclassing. You can create your gesture recognizers.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your responses. I haven't built for iOS before yet, am looking to port my Android solution. If the tap counts in UIEvents redundantly reflect prior UIEvents, it might be possible, assuming that iOS doesn't preempt the gestures. I guess I need to experiment with a demo to get my answers. Probably best for me to farm that out in case I end up wasting time learning Swift/iOS for nothing. I'll report back.